# LabelPropagation with TfidfVectorizer low accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I asked this question before and it is closed. Therefore I need to ask it again.
I'm master student in computer engineering department and struggling with Labelpropagation and my problem is about Labelpropagation.

I have below code and score is very low. I didn't understand where the problem is. I tried to use LabelPropagation with TfIdfVectorizer. But there is a problem about that code.

The problem is **low accuracy**. Result is about %28 and it is very low. We have only four categories. I had been hoping the result would have high accuracy. Am I right?

Can anybody help me?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelPropagation

ratiolabeled = 0.5

categories = [
     'alt.atheism',
     'talk.religion.misc',
     'comp.graphics',
     'sci.space'
]


data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', shuffle=True,           random_state=42, remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'),
                                categories=categories)
data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', shuffle=True, random_state=42, remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'),
                               categories=categories)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.8,  stop_words='english')

y_train, y_test = data_train.target, data_test.target
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)
labeled_indices, unlabeled_indices =    train_test_split(np.arange(len(y_train)), test_size=1-ratiolabeled,
                                                  random_state=43, stratify = y_train)
y_train[unlabeled_indices]=-1
lp_model = LabelPropagation(kernel='knn', n_neighbors=21, n_jobs=-1,  max_iter=20)
lp_model.fit(X_train.toarray(),y_train)

print("Accuracy = ", lp_model.score(X_train.toarray(),y_train))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `rbf` kernel?

Comment: I used rbf and accuracy become higher. But why?